# Не могу создавать файлы на диске C:

Tags: windows

Могу создать только [новую папку](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYdpQ.jpg).

В windows 7 помню, проблема решалась отключением контроля учётных записей. Сейчас у меня windows 8.1. Контроль учётных записей [отключил](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Da5VN.jpg). Что делать дальше -  не знаю.

Comment: А зачем файлы создавать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**(решение крайне не рекомендуется)**

---

Диск `C` не для хранения файлов, не знаю зачем такое может понадобиться, но лучше так не делать.

Но можно добавить необходимые права конкретному пользователю, а именно права на "запись" и "изменение" (первые чтобы создавать, вторые - чтобы можно было менять).

И стоит применить только для этой папки. А то можно поломать права на всём диске.

---

Если же надо просто единожды создать файл - лучше создать в другом месте и скопировать на диск.